# How can I get rid of the File Explorer folder name dropdown?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When I use File Explorer, I often get a dropdown below the folder field.

[image: File explorer]

This dropdown is annoyingly persistent: It takes multiple clicks to get rid of it so I can access the icons that are hidden by this dropdown. Sometimes the dropdown is long enough to obscure the list of files in the selected folder.
It also makes access to the folder field (for copying the folder path) more difficult.

1. What triggers this dropdown?
2. How can I disable it completely?

Comment: The "dropdown" should trigger only when the path bar has focus (eg when you click into it). This is the second time I've seen this general question in the last couple weeks, so I'm guessing there is a bug affecting a small subset of users.